# How to add formulas to a cell using script in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I'm trying to add a formula to a cell that will act as a reset button.
For example cell A1 is keeping track of how many times we use this the item, cell B1 copies the number from A1 and when the number gets to 25 I have to put-25, so the number will go back to 0 so when A1 says 26 B1 will say 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a script? as the same behavior can be done using formula easily.

#### Formula 1:

`=if(A1 < 25, A1, A1 - 25)`

[image: output]

Or if `A1` reaches 50 (and other multiples of 25 such as 75, 100, etc...), it will again subtract 25 to `B1`? If so, this formula should do it.

#### Formula 2:

`=MOD(A1, 25)`

[image: output2]

If you are really dead set in using script, then you can use `getFormula` to get the formula of the existing cell, and `setFormula` to set the formula on that specific cell.

The idea is when the `A1` value meets the condition (25 or greater), get the formula of `B1`, append `" - 25"` to it and then set it as the new formula. A part of your script should look similar to this if that's the behavior you want.

#### Code Snippet:

```
var valueA1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var formulaB1 = sheet.getRange("B1").getFormula();
if (valueA1 >= 25)
  sheet.getRange("B1").setFormula(formulaB1 + " - 25");
```

#### Sample data:

[image: before]

#### Running the function after changing A1 to `25`:

[image: after]